# Rupee symbol not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html

I want to display rupee symbol on web page I have used **&#8377** this code for rupee symbol it works fine in Firefox and chrome but not working in IE9,8,7

```
<p>&#8377 100/</p>
```

Please help me with this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: For supporting the rupee symbol you can go through [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/inr/). It will work. Hope it helps

Comment: This link may be helpful for you. http://www.design2core.com/myblog/css/how-to-use-new-indian-rupee-symbolwebrupee-on-your-webpage-or-blog/

Comment: Thanks Gunasseelan this link helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to achieve it across browsers is custom fonts ,  [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons)

usage :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
```